# C++ compilation issue when trying to insert into a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

C++ compiler error that i am getting is :

```
line 27: Error: Could not find a match for 
     std::multimap<std::string, std::vector<std::string>, 
                   std::less<std::string>, 
                   std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, 
                       std::vector<std::string>>>>
     ::insert(std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>) 
     needed in main().
1 Error(s) detected.
```

Below is my program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef multimap<string, vector<string> > mos_map;
typedef multimap<string, vector<string> >::iterator mos_map_it;

int main()
{

    mos_map mos;
    mos_map_it it;

    vector<string> v1;

    v1.push_back("a");
    v1.push_back("b");
    v1.push_back("c");
    v1.push_back("mo1");

    std::string a(*(v1.end()-1));

    mos.insert(std::pair< std::string, vector< std::string > >(a,v1));
    //Is the above not the right way to to insert an element into the map?
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is throwing a compilation error when i try to insert a vector as value with a string as a key.I am working on solaris.

Comment: You forgot to `#include <string>`.

Comment: even after adding #include<string> , i get the same error.

Comment: what is the compiler you use?

Comment: Use `make_pair(a, v1)`.

Comment: compiles fine on gcc 4.8.1, guess it includes <string> somewhere under the hood

Comment: Why do you mix `using namespace std` and qualifying `std::` ? you should do one or the other. (preferably remove the using)

Comment: Make pair also does nt work. my server is :> uname -a
SunOS phoenix 5.10 Generic_137138-09 i86pc i386 i86pc

Comment: also the insert you are inconsistent: you haven't qualified the vector in the same way as everything else. try changing `mos.insert(std::pair< std::string, vector< std::string > >(a,v1));
` to `mos.insert(std::pair< std::string, std::vector< std::string > >(a,v1));
` N.B. code also compiles under vs2012 as is so this could be sun specific....

Comment: @ caribou, even your suggestion did not work. Is this the problem with the solaris compiler? The compiler i am using is /opt/SUNWspro/bin/CC

Comment: Your code built on vs2012 and according to Balog under gcc 4.81 so I'd suggest there is something specific about your sun environment/compiler. I can't help any further as I don't have a sun environment.

Comment: i donno why other type of insertions are not working. But this worked.`mos.insert(mos_map::value_type(a,v1));`

Answer (score -1):

Right way to insert element in map is:

```
mos[a] = v1
```

(due to map has overloaded operator[])

Comment: It's the convenient way.  It's also the less efficient way: if `a` is not yet present in the map, a default value is created first, then `v1` is assigned to the new map entry.  This is not the case with `insert`.