# Segmentation fault which accessing a map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

In continuation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361645/c-compilation-issue-when-trying-to-insert-into-a-map) question I am trying to access a map. But i am getting a segmentation fault. Below is my code:

```
typedef multimap<string, vector<string> > mos_map;
typedef multimap<string, vector<string> >::iterator mos_map_it;

int main()
{

mos_map mos;
mos_map_it it;

vector<string> v1;

v1.push_back("a");
v1.push_back("b");
v1.push_back("c");
v1.push_back("mo1");

mos.insert(mos_map::value_type(*(v1.end()-1),v1));

for(it=mos.begin();it!=mos.end();it++);
{
cout<<(*it).first<<endl;//seg fault occurs here
}
```

Comment: FWIW, you can write `it->first`.

Comment: Even this(it->first) resulted in a core dump

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(it=mos.begin();it!=mos.end();it++);
//                                    ^
```

Your loop has empty body.

Some tips:

- Enable warnings:

  > warning: for loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
- Declare variables only when they are needed:

  ```
  for(auto it = mos.begin(); it != mos.end(); it++);
  {
      cout << (*it).first << endl;
  }
  ```

  This code will cause a compile time error:

  > error: use of undeclared identifier 'it'

Comment: @BalogPal, Yeah, I was adding it :)